# C#: Trying to invoke a method in a class

Tags: c#, invoke

I am programming a game. Each level has a class (level1, level2, etc) that tells the game which objects to set up plus other stuff. Each level shares an interface iLevel.

All objects in the scene have access to anything in iLevel, but sometimes I want to call a method that only exists in the specific level class.

For example:

```
public class Level1, iLevel {
    public int GetANumber() {
       return 5;
    }
}
```

The calling class needs to do this:

```
public class SomeObject {
    iLevel myLevel = new iLevel();
    int x = ... // now I need to call GetANumber() without knowing that object is Level1, Level2, etc.
}
```

I believe I need to use invoke somehow, but I wasn't able to get it to work. I read the documentation on msdn but I still wasn't able to get it to work.

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: You should read about interfaces, inheritance and method overriding first.

Comment: You should refer object oriented programming concepts that would help implementing these. The following [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) would give more idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here either u can use if condition with **is** and **as** operators or make iLevel an abstract class with GetNumber returning negative values by default.

```
public class SomeObject {
    iLevel myLevel = new iLevel();
    int x = -1;

    if(myLevel is Level1) {
        x = (myLevel is Level1).GetANumber();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public abstract class iLevel {
    public virtual int GetANumber() {
        return -1;
    }
}

public class Level1 : iLevel {
    public override int GetANumber() {
       return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: This(first option) is not a good object oriented programming practice.  Here you defeat the use of interface and generic programming. To better answer, the call to the special method in the case of Level1 should be invoked from within the method 'GetANumber' or any other method which is implemented in that class.

Comment: @Chris, I provided two solutions. First one won't affect existing system.

Comment: I saw your second post after my posting. My comment is for your  first option. Now, I edited my comment so that it wont confuse the users. The second option you have posted is a better one. Still there are some syntax errors in the class definition  in inheriting the base class and also the base class method is not declared with virtual. Even though the first one wont affect the existing system, it is not advisable to encourage such programming practice.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your feedback, I still didn't get your point in first comment, stating about special method (which is GetANumber I think).

Comment: I think the word special was not needed... In fact, I pointed the GetANumber method.